# Configuration in CloudBees for a Java EE 7 persistence application

Tags: database, jakarta-ee, glassfish, persistence, cloudbees

I have a Java EE 7/Glassfish 4 persistence application. I would like to deploy it in CloudBees with ClickStart. What I have to do the configuration in CloudBees? For example, the database?

Thank you in advance.

Leon

Answer (score 0):

CloudBees automatically inject bound database to your application as a JNDI resource. To bind a datasource, use the SDK as detailed on [wiki](http://wiki.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/Resource+Management).